# Eclipse SWT Open editor from TreeViewer

Tags: eclipse-rcp

In an RCP application, I am trying to open an editor when a user doubleclicks on a node in a TreeViewer.  The strategy I've used for this when the view contains a TableViewer is to pass the current state in the ExecutionEvent and in the open editor handler get the selections.  This strategy fails when used with a TreeViewer because getSelectionProvider() returns null.

Any suggestions for passing the selection to the handler? Or best practice for opening an editor from a TreeView?

Working from TableViewer

```java
// in doubleClick handler of view
ICommandService cmdService = (ICommandService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(ICommandService.class);
Command cmd = cmdService.getCommand("com.easa.acmotor.client.eclipse.motorOpenFromView");
ExecutionEvent eventCmd = new ExecutionEvent(cmd, new HashMap<String, String>(), this,
        ((IEvaluationService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IEvaluationService.class)).getCurrentState());
try {
    cmd.executeWithChecks(eventCmd);
} catch (Exception e) {
}


// in open editor handler
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
    IStructuredSelection sel = (IStructuredSelection) HandlerUtil.getActiveSite(event).getSelectionProvider().getSelection();
    // process selected items here opening an editor for each
```

Comment: Why not just call `IDE.openEditor` directly in the double click handler?

Comment: Greg - This is in an RCP application not the IDE.  I updated the question to reflect this context.

Comment: The `IDE` class is still included in many RCPs, use `IWorkbenchPage.openEditor` if not. As far as the selection being empty have you connected your tree viewer to the site selection provider?

Comment: Greg - thanks for the pointer to connecting the tree viewer to site selection.  I missed that bit of configuration.  If you enter an answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the view (or editor) site that your `TreeViewer` is the selection provider for the site.

In your ViewPart (or EditorPart) use something like:

```java
getSite().setSelectionProvider(treeViewer);
```

The `TreeViewer` class implements the `ISelectionProvider` required interface.